# How to subtract a date from another date using Robot Framework?

Tags: datetime, robotframework

i'm using Robot Framework Keyword `Subtract Date From Date` to test that a date is between 2 dates(For example 11/06/2020 is between 07/06/2020 and 20/06/2020), but i'm getting an error in my log file `ValueError: Invalid timestamp`. The date is a `String` extracted from a `Span Text` and i convert it to date This is my code :

```
${date}=        Get Current Date   result_format=datetime
${postdate}=    Get Text    xpath://app-post[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[2]//div[1]//div[2]//div[1]//div[2]//span[2]
${postdate}=    Convert Date    ${postdate}     date_format=%d/%m/%y
${date}=    Convert Date    ${date}     result_format=%d/%m/%y
${temp} =   Subtract Date From Date     ${postdate}     ${date}
Should Be True  ${temp}>=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't follow the allowed format for the keyword `Subtract Date From Date` mentioned here: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Date%20formats

`%y` will give you `20`, but that obviously is not enough. If I change it to `%Y`, it will give me `2020` for the current year, and the keyword `Subtract Date From Date` doesn't complain anymore about invalid timestamp. You'd also need to change it to something like `date_format=%Y/%m/%d`, that is to change the order of `%Y`, `%m`, and `%d`.

**EDIT:**

I can now see you're also using **date_format** as well as **result_format** with `Convert Date`. That's another bug in your code, you need to use `result_format` with both.

**EDIT 2:**

The full working example:

[image]

(And you're not using BuiltIn library here, these datetime keywords are from DateTime library)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the problem is also when i want to convert the date that is a String to Date i'm getting the error for example  `ValueError: time data '07/05/20' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d` that's why i've put `%y` instead of `%Y`

Comment: No, you're still using `%y`, that's why you have `20` in the error message as a year. **Capital** `%Y` will give you `2020` and the error will disappear.

Comment: @AbdoRabah: you can see the screenshot, you just need to use it in the same way

Answer (score 0):

The below script worked (Used the static PAST_DATE to check the sample run ):

```
${date}=    Set Variable    21
${month}=    Set Variable    12
${year}=    Set Variable    2019
${PAST_DATE}=    BuiltIn.Catenate    SEPARATOR=/    ${year}    ${month}    ${date}
Log    ${PAST_DATE}
${CURRENT_DATE}=    Get Current Date    result_format=%Y/%m/%d
Log    ${CURRENT_DATE}
${DIFFERNCE_IN_DAYS}=    Subtract Date from Date    ${CURRENT_DATE}    ${PAST_DATE}    verbose
Log    ${DIFFERNCE_IN_DAYS}
@{total_days}=    Split String    ${DIFFERNCE_IN_DAYS}
${final_days}=    Set Variable    ${total_days[0]}
Log    ${final_days}
Should be true    ${final_days} >= 0
```